# how to implement autocomplete in google search for a IOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, search

Im working with a developer in creating a iphone search bar in an applications that searches google when a user enters a query in my app.

I've been researching but haven't been able to find a solid answer.

Is there any code that I can implement where I can make use of the autocomplete/ website suggestion feature that google uses.

An app called flex search (http://chomp.com/a/1JPX/flex-search-mobile-research-app-for-google-bing-wikipedia) enables the same feature and I'm looking to implent that in my own IOS application when users search google.

Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the google suggestions in json format by sending a request to `http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&client=chrome&q=SEARCHTERM`

Comment: I used this one `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&q=YOUR_SEARCHTERM&key=YOUR_API_KEY` (I think you can use it even without the API-key). That way you get the plain JSON without the window.google.ac.h(...) method.

Comment: in my app, i would basically need the queries to come up so that when the user searches for something, they could press the suggestions which would be fowarded to the search box and then fowarded to the special google results page. would both of these methods would work the same or is there one that is faster/more reliable than the other? just trynna find the difference between highlycaffinated and jenna's answers :) thx

Comment: Both work the same, higlycaffeinated'd returns a result which is more suitable to be used in a webbrowser because it wraps the result in a function call which you'd have to remove in some way before passing it to the JSON parser. Mine returns just the plain JSON and therefore can not be used in a browser environment but you can pass it like it is to the JSON parser. Hm, I had a look at the documentation and it states that mine is depricated and you should use http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: thx! i see i think im somewhat understanding the process being kind of a rookie techie lol i looked at the link you gave me jenna and was wondering if theres any way i can implement a autocomplete code without having to use the api? it says that your only allowed 100 queries a day, and i feel like i will surpass that in 10 mins or so of usage. the searches will be processed in a simple search bar then fowarded to safari in an IOS application. I'm I correct in assuming that these codes are still applicable for a IOS app in this manner?

Comment: @highlycaffeinated - thanks for your answer! 
Would you know how issue the request for their image search (via Custom Search API)?